# Google Drive: Completely stop sharing

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing, google-drive-shared-folder

After finishing a project, I am trying to stop the sharing with collaborators.

I am following Google instructions [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494893), but the folder and files still shows the shared icon (one people over the folder or two people to the right of the file).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try refreshing the page?

Comment: The referred help article include instructions for several things. What steps you followed? Are the collaborators still able to access the files?